# Merge Sherepoint User Content

Tags: migration, user

Let's say you have UserA and UserB in AD. Sysadmin made a duplicate AD records for the same person. UserA has 17 assigned tasks and has 27 documents in personal document library. After a while, he starts using UserB account for windows login and sys admin disables UserA in AD. How can I transfer UserA sharepoint content to UserB? I miss merge user functionallity.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try on test users before this functionnality: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262141(office.12).aspx